# i want to show images on view page from controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
public ActionResult GetContentFromFTP()
{
    string[] FTP_Imagery = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\imgfiles\Imagery\");
    string[] FTP_Audio = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\audiofiles\Audio\");

    return View("showfiles");
}
```

This is my controller action in which two string array contain path of all audio file and image file. Now, I have to show these images on my view page "showfiles". Please suggest me how I will have to implement this ?

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc? This is essential ASP.NET MVC knowledge, you'll be struggling often if you're missing the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Controller.View method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) has an overload, that can pass also a *model* to the view, in this case your string array. Change your code to:

```
public ActionResult GetContentFromFTP()
{
    string[] FTP_Imagery = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\imgfiles\Imagery\");
    string[] FTP_Audio = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\audiofiles\Audio\");

    return View("showfiles", FTP_Imagery);
}
```

In your view use the *model* object to fetch the images and show them using standard HTML. One solution could look like this:

```
@foreach (var image in Model)
{
    <img src="@image" />
    <br />
}
```

A good tutorial about models and the communication between controller and view can be found at the [ASP.NET site - Intro to MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3) and [Accessing model from controller](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model%27s-data-from-a-controller).

Comment: Your solution only passes through one of the arrays; both will need to be passed, therefore you should really be creating an object to hold all the required data.

Comment: @AdrianWragg: You are right, but in OP's question i read `Now, I have to show these images on my view page "showfiles"` ... nothing about the audio files, so i assumed only the images are important in this case and thus my simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways of getting data from a Controller to the View, you can use the `ViewBag`

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetContentFromFTP()
{
    string[] FTP_Imagery = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\imgfiles\Imagery\");
    string[] FTP_Audio = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\audiofiles\Audio\");
    ViewBag.Add("FTP_Imagery", FTP_Imagery);
    ViewBag.Add("FTP_Audio", FTP_Audio);
    return View("showfiles");
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach(var img in ViewBag["FTP_Imagery"]){
    <!-- HTML for each image file -->
}

@foreach(var audio in ViewBag["FTP_Audio"]){
    <!-- HTML for each audio file -->
}
```

In my opinion you should take advantage of MVC's **strongly typed views** and have a ViewModel class (e.g. `ShowFilesViewModel`) which has properties anything you need for your view such as for each of these arrays
and then strongly type your View to that view model class:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ShowFilesViewModel()
{
    public string[] Images {get; set;}
    public string[] Audio {get; set;}
    // anything else you need for your view...
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetContentFromFTP()
{
    string[] FTP_Imagery = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\imgfiles\Imagery\");
    string[] FTP_Audio = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\audiofiles\Audio\");

    var viewModel = new ShowFilesViewModel() 
    {
        Images = FTP_Imagery;
        Audio = FTP_Audio;
    };

    return View("showfiles", viewModel);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model ShowFilesViewModel

@foreach(var image in Model.Images){
    <!-- HTML for an image file -->
}
@foreach(var image in Model.Audio){
    <!-- HTML for an audio file -->
}
```

Comment: I have used this same concept but My images are not showing on corresponding view page. Please suggest me

Comment: It may be worth asking a new question in which you show your model, view and controller code so we are able to see where the problem may lie.

Comment: I am just asking to share in which type of control I will show image on view page from foreach loop ?

Comment: Use standard html; you could use an unordered list `<ul>` with each image being a list item `<li>` containing an `<img src="@image"/>`

Answer (score 1):

you can just creat a viewmodel class contain the media and image array like this:

```
class ViewModel{
   Public string[] Images {get;set;}
   Public string[] Videos {get;set;}
}
```

so in you action :

```
public ActionResult GetContentFromFTP()
{
string[] FTP_Imagery = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\imgfiles\Imagery\");
string[] FTP_Audio = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\abc\audiofiles\Audio\");
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(){Images = FTP_Imagery,Videos=FTP_Audio };

return View("showfiles", vm);
}
```

view:

```
@foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
   <img src="@image" />
   <br />
}
@foreach (var video in Model.Videos)
{
   <video src="@video " />
   <br />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Made this for play video in MVC and get this video from controller through custom action filter may be this can be very useful to you.

1 ) Add new class file 'VideoDataResult.cs' for custom action filter

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Hosting;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace PlayVideoInMVC.CustomDataResult
    {
        public class VideoDataResult : ActionResult
        {
    /// <summary>
    /// The below method will respond with the Video file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {

        var strVideoFilePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/VideoFiles/Test2.mp4");

        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test2.mp4");

        var objFile = new FileInfo(strVideoFilePath);

        var stream = objFile.OpenRead();
        var objBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(objBytes, 0, (int)objFile.Length);
        context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(objBytes);

            } 
        }
    }
```

2 Add 'VideoDataController' controller file 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using PlayVideoInMVC.CustomDataResult;
using System.Web.Mvc;

```
    namespace PlayVideoInMVC.Controllers
    {
        public class VideoDataController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /VideoData/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return new VideoDataResult();
            }

        }
    }
```

3 ) Add HTML markup of 'View' :
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }

```
    <h2>Play Video</h2>
    <h3><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "VideoData")">Download Video</a> </h3>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="@Url.Action("Index", "VideoData")" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```